# How to disable variables multi-coloring in KDevelop?

Tags: kdevelop

Is there any way to force KDevelop to use only a single color for all variables?

[image: Screen from KDevelop]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open `Settings -> Configure KDevelop...`, select `Language Support` tab, move `Local colorization intensity` slider to the left.